# Passing two params to sub-level treeview with HierarchicalDataSource

Tags: treeview, kendo-ui

How can I send 2 params to sub-level treeview.

Sample:

```
var data2 = {
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: function(options) {
        console.log(options);
        return kendo.format("/url2/", [options.param1, options.param2]);
      },
      dataType: "jsonp"
    }
  },
  schema: {
    model: {
      id: "param4",
      fields: {
        param4: {type: "number"},
        param5: {type: "string"},
      },
      hasChildren: "param4",
    }
  }
};
var data1 = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: "/url/",
      dataType: "jsonp"
    }
  },
  schema: {
    model: {
      id: "param1",
      fields: {
        param1: {type: "number"},
        param2: {type: "number"},
        param3: {type: "string"},
      },
      hasChildren: "param1",
      children: data2
    }
  }
});

$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
  dataSource: data1,
  dataTextField: ["param3", "param5"]
});
```

When I debug code with `console.log(options);` only params that pass is `param1`.
How I can get `param2`?

There is no sample or documention at [KendoUi Demos](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/remote-data.html), is there a easy way or I must just log all select path for this?

Comment: I agree with @BurkeHolland solutions. You should keep in mind that only the `id` of `data1` is received in `options` in the `url` function of `data2`. I also do recommend you to review your `model` since it is pretty odd that `param1` and `param4` are used as `id` and also as fields for knowing if a tree level `hasChildren`. Are you sure about this? Assuming that `id` must be unique how do you specify that a node doesn't have children, setting it's `id` to 0? Also, `hasChildren` should be considered as `boolean`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the ID of the item which you can use to get the object from the datasource.

```
var item = data1.get(options.param1);
```

Here is an example...

http://jsbin.com/alibem/1/edit